# pandas aggregate multiple columns during pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame((['1990-01-01','A','S1','2','string2','string3'],
 ['1990-01-01','A','S2','1','string1','string4'],
 ['1990-01-01','A','S3','1','string5','string6']),columns= 
 ["date","type","status","count","s1","s2")


           date type status count       s1       s2
 0  1990-01-01    A     S1     2  string2  string3
 1  1990-01-01    A     S2     1  string1  string4
 2  1990-01-01    A     S3     1  string5  string6
 ...
```

I want to get bellow result
(each date and each type should have single row, and get the min of s1 column, get max of s2 column)

```
date             type       S1    S2   S3    min_s1        max_s2
1990-01-01       A           2     1   1     string1      string6
```

I tried to use `pivot_table`

```
df.pivot_table(index=['date','type'],columns=['status'],values=['count','s1','s2'], aggfunc={
'count':np.sum, 
's1': np.min,
's2': np.max
})
```

But this would only get bellow result, which leads to multiple columns and not the final result.

```
                count             s1                         s2
status             S1 S2 S3       S1       S2       S3       S1       S2       S3
date       type
1990-01-01 A        2  1  1  string2  string1  string5  string3  string4  string6
```

Anyone idea? Thanks.

Comment: please check your input data again, the example dataframe is not what you show as output.

Comment: How do you define min_s1 and max_s2?  What is logic to compute these values, since they seem to be str data?

Comment: string is comparable, so use the default logic. like 'a' < 'b' , '1'<''2'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like you want to combine a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
(df.pivot(index=['date','type'],columns='status', values='count')
   .join(df.groupby(['date', 'type']).agg({'s1': 'min', 's2': 'max'}))
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
         date type S1 S2 S3       s1       s2
0  1990-01-01    A  2  1  1  string1  string6
```